# How sqlite can be used after deleting local database file?

Tags: database, sqlite

I tried to open local database file by sqlite3. After that I delete this file or move it to another location, I still can execute SQL queries on this database.

```sh
$ sqlite3 test.db
sqlite> select * from my_table limit 10;
        <10 rows>

// then I delete "test.db" file

sqlite> select * from my_table order by random() limit 10;
        <10 random rows>
```

So I have 2 questions?

1. If "test.db" is 2GB file, sqlite load it and store it in memory?
2. If not, how sqlite can still execute SQL queries on non-existent database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is not a sqlite "function", is how linux work with open files.

On Linux or Unix systems, deleting a file via rm or through a file manager application will unlink the file from the file system's directory structure; however, if the file is still open (in use by a running process) it will still be accessible to this process and will continue to occupy space on disk. Therefore such processes may need to be restarted before that file's space will be cleared up on the filesystem.

For more information:

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2316